# Get properties of Html element in runtime

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a map in React:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
    {data.map((value, index) => {
        return (
            <>
                <tr> {/* I want to receive that row's left coordinates */}
                    <td>
                        <div style={
                            {
                                position: 'absolute',
                                left:0 //here I want reference to coordinates of current tr of map loop
                            }
                        }>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </>
        )
    })
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I achieve that? I've tried `useRef`, but it's looks no possible. I need this `tr` coordinates in order to stick a html element with absolute coordinates to it.

Comment: Well that tr hasn't been rendered yet, so there is no 'left coordinates'

Comment: I think you'll find your answer in CSS rather than by programmatic code.. Have you tried wrapping your absolute div with a `position: relative;` div, so the absolute position is relative to it? Or maybe setting the `tr` or `td` itself `position: relative;` ?

Comment: Thanks, I'll do research and try to use a different technique.

Answer (score 0):

I just used `useRef` to the parent element:

```
<table>
    <tbody ref={myRef}> /{/* this is ref */}
    {data.map((value, index) => {
        return (
            <>
                <tr> {/* I want to receive that row's left coordinates */}
                    <td>
                        <div style={
                            {
                                position: 'absolute',
                                left:0 //here I want reference to coordinates of current tr of map loop
                            }
                        }>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </>
        )
    })
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```